# I'm confused about the overall structure of this sentence

Tags: grammar, translation, syntax

For context, this sentence is taken from exercise 1, instruction 3.
https://www.docdroid.net/JUGEND2/img-20170606-0001-new.pdf.html

> 費用｛ひよう｝が高｛たか｝いと課長｛かちょう｝が言｛い｝ったので、半分｛はんぶん｝自分｛じぶん｝で払｛はら｝うから、行｛い｝かせてほしいと交渉｛こうしょう｝してください。

In this sentence, I feel like everything's positioned inverted.
The only way I can make sense of it in a translation is by reversing this inversion.
This is what I would come up with:

> Please barter, because the chairman said the cost is high, and because you pay one half yourself if you wish to be let go(ne?).

Since these measures to beat sense into it feel so strong, I wanted to ask you for your opinion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 費用が高いと課長が言ったので、半分自分で払うから、行かせてほしいと交渉してください。

Probably adding brackets will help you a lot:

> 費用が高いと課長が言ったので、「半分自分で払うから、行かせてほしい」と交渉してください。

Roughly translates to:

> The chairman said the cost is high. So please negotiate, (saying) "I will pay half of the cost by myself, so please allow me to go (to the seminar)". (or literally, "I want you to let me go")

I split the sentence into two for the sake of clarity.

Comment: Thanks!
But what did you do with ...言った_ので_   and ...払う_から_ ?
Don't they have to be translated into something along the lines of "because" here?

Comment: @Narktor `AのでB` and `AからB` can be both translated either as "B because A" or "A, so B". The former using "because" may be more literal, but I thought the latter flows better in this case.